# Ubuntu 20.04 UI rendering glitches after upgrading from 18.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, xorg, display, intel-graphics

I was using ubuntu 18.04 for long time and then I upgraded to 20.04 but faced lot of problems,specially relating to display and graphics drivers. but I anyway solved this here [Ubuntu Black Sreen problem after upgrading from 18.04 to latest 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331627/ubuntu-black-sreen-problem-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-latest-20-04) but now I have new problems.

my screen gets rendered after every mouse move or for any event multiple times that I cant ignore.. it just gets rendered multiple times in a row that is noticable visually and making the screen/mouse laggy. I can barely point my mouse any specific area or type clearly. I saw I am not the first to encounter this type of problem in 20.04.

here is the video of the problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fzrzGRWC3PoT5Mdy4bKpjcSMfHRcTV0J/view?usp=sharing

I tried [X11 configs and rendering glitches Ubuntu (Desktop) 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276928/x11-configs-and-rendering-glitches-ubuntu-desktop-20-04) and https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/screen-glitching-problem-with-20-04/3661/6 as my "inxi -G" command shows

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev,intel 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6
```

but no luck. what the heck is the problem and is there really any solution or should I just revert back to 18.04? Please help and Thanks in advance

Comment: First advice. Do a fresh install, i.e., wiping the previous install. Then, the system will be installed with the best defaults, and not based on some potentially outdated configuration of your previous install.

Answer (score 1):

`renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6` shows that the intel driver does not support mesa/opengl - so you do not have any 3D support (like transparency etc).
This leads to the laggy appearance you've described.

You might check in `/etc/modprobe.d/` if the intel driver is somewhere blacklistet otherwise my advice is to save your data an reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 from the scratch. I've had often problems with upgrades and always could solve them by reinstalling.

Ubuntu has written a [how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) install from USB Stick.

Comment: can u give me a hint for reinstalling? as I faced lots of problems while upgrading and um really confused what todo :)

Comment: See my extended answer - you are free to search around in this forum. If you have problems with the [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)  you should ask a new question.